# Downlading works fine on wifi but not on data

Tags: downloading

I am trying to download a season on my mobilw with android app. As soon as it connects to my office wifi it starts downlading but its not downloading on my mobile data. When downlaod was initiated it was downloading perfectly fine. My mobile data is much faster than my WiFi so i want mobile data downloading. Please help, from my end i have checked all the settings

Comment: Is background data ON?

Answer (score 0):

Please mention through which app you are trying to download.
one possible reason it is not downloading on mobile data is most apps don't download content on mobile data by default, you have to go to the app settings and check if there is any option saying **download only on wifi**, if that's the case then just enable downloading on mobile data from there.